# Post API vs import data through the app (insert it as customer/tester through the app forntend)

Tags: api, selenium, postman

For testing API, I need to set some data.

Is it better (cheaper and faster) to import data through the app like regular user. Using frontend which will set and store the data into data base, and I will test that data and have it stored forever, until I decide that data needs to be changed.

Or is it better to do a POST method with API and set data through the API.

I assume that programing API POST method is more expensive and time consuming then using regular app. And also data is stored only while test is runing (that is less memory on other hand, but assume that few MB of DB is not giving higher advantage).
Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Uploading anything through UI is more costlier and slower than uploading through API its not the other way:

Thats why we have the inverted pyramid tobe anti pattern in testing:

[image]

Ideal pattern is the testing pyramid or inverted cone

Comment: This is automated vs manual... Manual import in this case is faster then programing it...You dont need to program preconditions or to mentain it in API post method.And my question is in that direction.

Comment: This is not automated vs manual , it is process speed in each layer . It's the same for manual or automated

Comment: Your application uses api in backend to do this operation , so when you use UI for adding test data it also includes the front end data processing . So instead if you use api directly then you save that processing time and also it's easy to add data in api if you just store the api body structure in advance